# How handle success load of data with bootstrap modal?

Tags: ajax, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

We have:

```
$('#myModal').modal({
    show: true,
    remote: '/some/api/url/',
    //onComplete: function() ???
    //success: function() ???
});
```

How for example make console.log() every time when data successfuly loaded?

Comment: "python" tag removed - this is in no way a Python question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals-options):

> remote
>
> This option is deprecated since v3.3.0 and has been removed in v4. We recommend instead using client-side templating or a data binding framework, or calling jQuery.load yourself.

In any case, you can use:

> loaded.bs.modal    This event is fired when the modal has loaded content using the remote option

So the code, in your case will be:

```
$('#myModal').on('loaded.bs.modal', function (e) {
      // do something...
})
```

An example:

```js
$('#myModal').modal({
  show: true,
  remote: 'https://api.github.com/users/defunkt'
});
$('#myModal').on('loaded.bs.modal', function (e) {
  $("#myModal").css({"height":'150px',"overflow-y":"auto"});
  console.log('remote content loaded');
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                ...
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: i hear already, content loaded only once? when i try to load content again but with the same link it can not be updated?

Comment: @Lem You are right: ....If a remote URL is provided, content will be loaded one time.... So, I suggest you to load outside the content using by yourself the jQuery load.